# Discord.py rank card add text (Pillow)

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

So i am making the chat !rank command for my own discord server, i have the database done with mongodb  , i have done the rank card format too by following a tutorial , but i wanted to add a total xp field that the code in the tutorial don't have and i am a total noob with pillow.
My current code:

```
async def make_rank_image(self, member: discord.Member, rank, level, xp, final_xp,status,Totalxp):#Totalxp is unused and will be used in the totalxp text field
        user_avatar_image = str(member.avatar_url_as(format='png', size=512))
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(user_avatar_image) as resp:
                avatar_bytes = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())

        img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 240))
        logo = Image.open(avatar_bytes).resize((200, 200))
        # Stack overflow helps :)
        bigsize = (logo.size[0] * 3, logo.size[1] * 3)
        mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
        draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
        mask = mask.resize(logo.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        logo.putalpha(mask)
        ##############################
        img.paste(logo, (20, 20), mask=logo)

        # Black Circle
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, 'RGB')
        draw.ellipse((152, 152, 208, 208), fill='#000')

        # Placing offline or Online Status
        if str(status) == "online":
            draw.ellipse((155, 155, 205, 205), fill='#3BA55B')
        elif str(status) == "idle":
            draw.ellipse((155, 155, 205, 205), fill='#F9A61A')
        elif str(status) == "dnd":
            draw.ellipse((155, 155, 205, 205), fill='#EC4245')
        else:
            draw.ellipse((155, 155, 205, 205), fill='#737F8D')
        ##################################

        # Working with fonts
        big_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('ABeeZee-Regular.otf', 60)
        medium_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('ABeeZee-Regular.otf', 40)
        small_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('ABeeZee-Regular.otf', 30)
        extra_small_front=ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('ABeeZee-Regular.otf',10)
        # Placing Level text (right-upper part)
        text_size = draw.textsize(f"{level}", font=big_font)
        offset_x = 1000 - 15 - text_size[0]
        offset_y = 5
        draw.text((offset_x, offset_y), f"{level}", font=big_font, fill="#11ebf2")
        text_size = draw.textsize('LEVEL', font=small_font)

        offset_x -= 5 + text_size[0]
        offset_y = 35
        draw.text((offset_x, offset_y), "LEVEL", font=small_font, fill="#11ebf2")
        #totalxp field
        How do you do this?????????



        # Placing Rank Text (right upper part)
        text_size = draw.textsize(f"#{rank}", font=big_font)
        offset_x -= 15 + text_size[0]
        offset_y = 8
        draw.text((offset_x, offset_y), f"#{rank}", font=big_font, fill="#fff")

        text_size = draw.textsize("RANK", font=small_font)
        offset_x -= 5 + text_size[0]
        offset_y = 35
        draw.text((offset_x, offset_y), "RANK", font=small_font, fill="#fff")

        # Placing Progress Bar
        # Background Bar
        bar_offset_x = logo.size[0] + 20 + 100
        bar_offset_y = 160
        bar_offset_x_1 = 1000 - 50
        bar_offset_y_1 = 200
        circle_size = bar_offset_y_1 - bar_offset_y

        # Progress bar rect greyier one
        draw.rectangle((bar_offset_x, bar_offset_y, bar_offset_x_1, bar_offset_y_1), fill="#727175")
        # Placing circle in progress bar

        # Left circle
        draw.ellipse((bar_offset_x - circle_size // 2, bar_offset_y, bar_offset_x + circle_size // 2,
                      bar_offset_y + circle_size), fill="#727175")

        # Right Circle
        draw.ellipse(
            (bar_offset_x_1 - circle_size // 2, bar_offset_y, bar_offset_x_1 + circle_size // 2, bar_offset_y_1),
            fill="#727175")

        # Filling Progress Bar

        bar_length = bar_offset_x_1 - bar_offset_x
        # Calculating of length
        # Bar Percentage (final_xp - current_xp)/final_xp

        # Some variables
        progress = (final_xp - xp) * 100 / final_xp
        progress = 100 - progress
        progress_bar_length = round(bar_length * progress / 100)
        pbar_offset_x_1 = bar_offset_x + progress_bar_length

        # Drawing Rectangle
        draw.rectangle((bar_offset_x, bar_offset_y, pbar_offset_x_1, bar_offset_y_1), fill="#11ebf2")
        # Left circle
        draw.ellipse((bar_offset_x - circle_size // 2, bar_offset_y, bar_offset_x + circle_size // 2,
                      bar_offset_y + circle_size), fill="#11ebf2")
        # Right Circle
        draw.ellipse(
            (pbar_offset_x_1 - circle_size // 2, bar_offset_y, pbar_offset_x_1 + circle_size // 2, bar_offset_y_1),
            fill="#11ebf2")

        def convert_int(integer):
            if integer>=1000:
                integer = round(integer / 1000, 2)
                return f'{integer}K'
            else:
                return integer

        # Drawing Xp Text
        text = f"/ {convert_int(final_xp)} XP"
        xp_text_size = draw.textsize(text, font=small_font)
        xp_offset_x = bar_offset_x_1 - xp_text_size[0]
        xp_offset_y = bar_offset_y - xp_text_size[1] - 10
        draw.text((xp_offset_x, xp_offset_y), text, font=small_font, fill="#727175")

        text = f'{convert_int(xp)} '
        xp_text_size = draw.textsize(text, font=small_font)
        xp_offset_x -= xp_text_size[0]
        draw.text((xp_offset_x, xp_offset_y), text, font=small_font, fill="#fff")

        # Placing User Name
        text = member.display_name
        if len(text)>=15:
            text_size=draw.textsize(text, font=small_font)
            text_offset_x = bar_offset_x - 10
            text_offset_y = bar_offset_y - text_size[1] - 10
            draw.text((text_offset_x, text_offset_y), text, font=small_font, fill="#fff")
        else:
            text_size = draw.textsize(text, font=medium_font)
            text_offset_x = bar_offset_x - 10
            text_offset_y = bar_offset_y - text_size[1] - 10
            draw.text((text_offset_x, text_offset_y), text, font=medium_font, fill="#fff")


        # Placing Discriminator
        text = f'#{member.discriminator}'
        text_offset_x += text_size[0] + 10
        text_size = draw.textsize(text, font=small_font)
        text_offset_y = bar_offset_y - text_size[1] - 10
        draw.text((text_offset_x-10, text_offset_y), text, font=small_font, fill="#727175")

        bytes = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(bytes, 'PNG')
        bytes.seek(0)
        return bytes
```

And it will return a image that looks like this:
[image]

i want the total xp text field to be inline with the Rank and Level field but in the same time right on top of the user name, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't defined "ImageDraw" and "ImageFont"

Answer (score 0):

Just use
from Pillow import ImageDraw, ImageFont

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).